# iOS: Read traffic usage from device

Tags: ios, network-traffic

I would like to know the amount of data traffic my iPhone consumed for a given period of time like you can see in the preferences.

Is this possible to get this information? Or even better: Is it possible to register for traffic usage information that my app can analyze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Apple doesn't allow developers access to this kind of information. I don't think you could access it without risking your app being rejected when submitted to Apple.

Comment: does this use the system's counter or its own though?

Comment: uses its own counter. Wondering how they did it :-?

Comment: indeed - maybe something through multitasking?

Comment: I meant maybe you can configure it to listen to the network when the app is running in the background

Comment: this could be very unprecise. e